# How can I remove text outliers from the white borders in the output PDF?

Tags: urls

For example in this accompanied image.
I want to write my script in a way that cuts off the light blue text outliers.

[image: Accompanied Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font looks as if the problem occurs only web addresses.

Solution: add the `xurl` package to your file